# C# How to move button controls from right to left with animation?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have array of buttons with location&images then i want to see it moving from right to left, let's say 2seconds interval. Here is my relevant code.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button[] buttonanimal = new Button[21];


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++)
        {
            buttonanimal[i] = new Button();
            buttonprop(buttonanimal[i]);

            if(i>=1&i<=4)
            {
                Point[] points = new Point[4];

                points[0] = new Point(100, 100);
                points[1] = new Point(400, 100);
                points[2] = new Point(700, 100);
                points[3] = new Point(1000, 100);

                buttonanimal[i].Visible = true;
                buttonanimal[i].Location = points[i - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    private void buttonprop(Button buttons)
    {
        buttons.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        buttons.Visible = false;
        Controls.Add(buttons);
    }


    private void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point[] points = new Point[4];

        points[0] = new Point(100, 100);
        points[1] = new Point(400, 100);
        points[2] = new Point(700, 100);
        points[3] = new Point(1000, 100);

        for (int i=1;i<=20;i++)
        {
            if(buttonanimal[i].Visible==true)
            {
                buttonanimal[i].Visible = false;

                buttonanimal[i + 1].Visible = true;
                buttonanimal[i + 2].Visible = true;
                buttonanimal[i + 3].Visible = true;
                buttonanimal[i + 4].Visible = true;

                buttonanimal[i + 1].Location = points[i - 1];
                buttonanimal[i + 2].Location = points[i - 2];
                buttonanimal[i + 3].Location = points[i - 3];
                buttonanimal[i + 4].Location = points[i - 4];

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have 4 visible button at the start. When you pressed ButtonNext. The first visible button(button1) at the left will gone and it will replace by button2 and so forth. I want too see the 4buttons moving from right to left.

Comment: If you want animations move to wpf. Simple as that. Else you'll have to manual implement it.

Comment: @Carl WPF vs WinForms has nothing to do with moving buttons across the screen at a set interval; OP just needs a `Timer`

Comment: @CoolBots It makes a difference when you have to write this chunck of code (in question) against few lines in xaml which is taking care of view related logic.

Comment: @Carl you're missing the point - the question is in regards to a specific setting; which you're essentially suggesting to discard and re-write... by the way, what "chunk of code"? It's a few lines, no matter what you use to implement it

Comment: @CoolBots This very point movement could be done seamlessly and distributed equaly within given time frame, which as I said before is few lines.

Comment: @Carl I agree, nothing easier than `button.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, new ThicknessAnimation( ... ));`

Comment: @carl "rewrite in a different platform" isn't really a solution to the problem though. We have to assume that he cannot do that unless told otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) that's set to 2-second (2000ms) interval, and update button positions in the event handler of the [`Tick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Here's an example you can adapt to your code, showing how to move a single button, called `myButton`, horizontally across the screen:

In class scope (global to your form):

```
//Declare and instantiate a Timer
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

In your form's `Load` event handler:

```
timer.Interval = 2000;  //set interval to 2 seconds
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;  //wire up event handler;
timer.Start();  //start the timer
```

In your form:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Move the button by 1 pixel
    myButton.Location = new Point(myButton.Location.X + 1, myButton.Location.Y)

    //Stop the timer once the button reaches the right edge
    if(myButton.Location.X + myButton.Width >= ClientSize.Width)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an interface and some classes for Animations. Then handle a array (or list) of these animation objects. This way the coupling between the parts is very low.

A simple Interface could look like:

```
interface IAnimator
{
    void Start();
    void Stop();
}
```

Then a very basic example for a class that can handle a control could look like:

```
public class CControlAnimator: IAnimator
{
    public Control control { get; set; }
    private Timer timer;
    // Data needed for animation

    public CControlAnimator()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += TimerTick;
    }

    public virtual void Start()
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public virtual void Stop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do the animation
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(control.Location.X + 2, control.Location.Y);
        }
    }
```

Now you could use it like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    IAnimator[] animators = new CControlAnimator[21];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            CControlAnimator animator = new CControlAnimator();
            animators[i] = animator;
            animator.control = new Button();
            // ...more init
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 5;
        animators[i].Start();
    }
```

The animator should know what the concreate animation look like and since you work with an interface, you could create many different concreate animators and handle them in the same way...

Comment: How would I use this interface / class to set my buttons to move in various directions? Some left, some right, some diagonal? ...would I need to create a sub-class for *each movement* and override `TimerTick` (which I suppose should be declared `virtual`)? If so, your system, while elaborate, seems rather... limited. Also, are you not creating an instance of `Timer` *per object* being animated? 20 objects, 20 timers?...

Comment: This answer is only showing a starting point. It's in your decission to make a different class for each kind of movement or a general one with maybe a 'moving path' component. So there is no limitation at all. And yes, the methods should be virtual to be ready for further inheritance (changed).

Comment: I'd love to see the moving path component implementation. What about animations that require other actions, like a button that also changes colors while moving, which isn't a "path"? And the `Timer` per object issue? Your system is not useable without sub-classing. The interface idea is nice though; the class implementing it is deeply flawed.

Comment: Wow, please slow down, many questions in one comment. As an idea for a moving path component you could create a class with starting point, ending point and a function to calulate the intermediate point by time difference. Of course can you implement a separate class for color animation, or put it in the same one. What you prefer. And you should use sub-classing to organise. The Timer can become an issue when using many many animations, but the example does not look like that. And even in that case, improve it. So in the end, again, it is only a starting point. What deeply flaws do you mean?